# Rails. Add a virtual attribute to a User object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, api

I am developing an API in Rails 3. I am fetching users from the database. This works fine but I want to add an "attribute" to the output called Contact_data. This "attribute" or what it is called does not have a counterpart in the database I just need it in the JSON output so that I can add an array to it.

How can this be done?

The current output is: http://pastie.org/1849048. I would like for it to appear for example just below the bio attribute.

Comment: Do you wan't that attribute to be part of the class, but not being on the database? Or you want it out of the class and only used on the json output moment?

Comment: I want it to be a "placeholder" for an array. I do not want it to be a part of the database.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question above. Do you want it to be used only at the json output moment or other places too?

Comment: Only for the JSON output please.